# Making table with div base structure for my responsive project

Tags: html, css

In my new project I'm using bootstrap and css both and I'm making responsive table using div base structure. I am trying this example for making table but my page is like below image:
[image] 
I am trying to put below image structure:

[image]

Problem is in only 1x3 tuple. 
 `

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="table" style="border:1px solid black;">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6">1</div>
       <div class="col-md-6">2</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">1</div>
       <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
       <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">1</div>
       <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
       <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: Should you give me correct link for study of this problem and I will try to learn more about that. Because I'm not much known about designing the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your code I'm correct your code. Change first col-md-6 to col-md-4 and then change second col-md-6 to col-md-8. If after this you do not understand then go with my code.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
 div{
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  </style>

<div class=" table table-bordered"  >
    <div class="row " >
         <div class="col-md-4">
             1
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-8">
            2
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                3
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

see my code snippet in full screen of your device.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question, the top values should `col-md-4` and `col-md-8`, not 6 and 6:

```
<div class=" table " style="border:1px solid black;">
    <div class="row ">
         <div class="col-md-4">
             1
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-8">
            2
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                3
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
 <div class=" table " style="border:1px solid black;">
    <div class="row ">
         <div style="width:35%;float:left;border:1px solid black;">
             1
         </div>
         <div style="width:65%;float:left;border:1px solid black;">
            2
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
         <div style="width:35%;float:left;border:1px solid black;">
            1
        </div>
         <div style="width:30%;float:left;border:1px solid black;">
            2
        </div>
         <div style="width:35%;float:left;border:1px solid black;">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
         <div style="width:35%;float:left;border:1px solid black;">
            1
        </div>
         <div style="width:30%;float:left;border:1px solid black;">
            2
        </div>
         <div style="width:35%;float:left;border:1px solid black;">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```